# How to update field based on another field in table in Doctrine2?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, sql-update, dql

I have table with two columns: `price` and `constant`.

I would like to run update on all entries in table to update `price` based on `constant * coefficient`.

How could I do such query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with a DQL query:

```
$em->createQuery('
    UPDATE entityClass e
    SET e.price = e.constant * 33;
');
```

You can also do that with raw SQL:

```
$em->getConnection()->executeUpdate('
    UPDATE entity_table_name AS e
    SET e.price = e.constant * 33;
');
```

You could also add a listener on the preUpdate & prePersist doctrine event, so that these values are updated automatically.

See http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#preupdate for an example.

So that each time you save your entity, it will update the related field automatically.

Comment: Actually I would like to do a bulk update. There are a lot of records (several thousands)  and I would like to do one query for all of them.